# Randomly iterate over ArrayList<Integer> in Java

Tags: java

Seems a very basic question. I've an `ArrayList<Integer> al` and I would like to iterate over it. Normally,

```
for(int i : al) {
    // some code
}
```

does the trick. But my requirement is to iterate not in sequence but randomly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) on the list.

Note that this will shuffle the list itself, so if order is important you should make a copy of it (and shuffle the copy).

```
List<Customer> newList = new ArrayList<>( oldList ) ;
Collections.shuffle( newList ) ;
```

Alternatively you could create a random array which has elements `0 - List.size()-1` and using those as indices to access "random" elements in the `List`.

Comment: Interesting that you got the 'answer' even though it's not solving the question. I think the poster is ok with a shuffled list which will give random order

Comment: That doesn't work: Collections.shuffle(Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArraysList<>()); The poster may actually be ok with the answer you gave because he actually WANTED that. But the question as stated is not answered here. And, I can break your solution. Not all List are modifiable. and iteration is a read-only operation

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Didn't I state in the answer this operation will shuffle the list itself, and they should make a copy of it and shuffle the copy if that was necessary? Your objection is unnecessarily pedantic.

Comment: The question was: "Random Iteration" -- I will give back my vote. On more carefully looking at it you alternate does describe, more-or-less my approach. That is a general answer I suppose. Collection.shuffle just isn't an answer to the question. But then again, maybe that was ultimately what the poster wanted. Too funny though: The question is like 4+ years old

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Your approach is basically what the last sentence of my answer describes. It's really a matter of preference. The OP seemed satisfied enough with my answer.

Comment: "... a random array which has **[distinct]** elements..."

Answer (score 5):

Use the following class:

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomPermuteIterator implements Enumeration<Long> {
    int c = 1013904223, a = 1664525;
    long seed, N, m, next;
    boolean hasNext = true;

    public RandomPermuteIterator(long N) throws Exception {
        if (N <= 0 || N > Math.pow(2, 62)) throw new Exception("Unsupported size: " + N);
        this.N = N;
        m = (long) Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(N) / Math.log(2)));
        next = seed = new Random().nextInt((int) Math.min(N, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RandomPermuteIterator r = new RandomPermuteIterator(100);
        while (r.hasMoreElements()) System.out.print(r.nextElement() + " ");
        //output:50 52 3 6 45 40 26 49 92 11 80 2 4 19 86 61 65 44 27 62 5 32 82 9 84 35 38 77 72 7 ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return hasNext;
    }

    @Override
    public Long nextElement() {
        next = (a * next + c) % m;
        while (next >= N) next = (a * next + c) % m;
        if (next == seed) hasNext = false;
        return  next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be much interested in an explanation of why this works. And, a test that shows variance of < 1%. This is interesting if it's actually correct

Comment: This is an adaptation of LCGs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). By choosing parameters that guarantee full-periodicity you can randomly enumerate numbers within a range without repetition.

Comment: Although this kind of takes the question off-topic, reference to an interesting algorithm won't pass software quality muster. After all, the algorithm can be perfectly sound but the devil is in the details. Witness why crypto functions are routinely hacked via side channels (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack) -- How would you how implementation correctness? You would basically have to show that, after applying the central limit theorem you have a p value < .01. I vote to re-ask this question on codereview and let it grow from there. Thoughts?

Comment: I am absolutely sure that crypto implementations get owned via side-channels. I am a seasoned software veteran and worked for Amazon right in their checkout pipeline; downtime was measured in $1Ms/min of loss. Your code might produce what look to be visually correct results but no one at Amazon or Google would just accept this without a test. On that matter I definitely know my subject. I would welcome your feedback and education in a direct channel. This being the internet you don't need to care if I am offended. If your intent is to educate and not insult then contact me (first.last@gmail)

Answer (score 3):

How about this way (more functional); it even includes a main() to demonstrate. Basically, generate random numbers in the range of your list size until you have 1 of them all. We use HashSet to take care of duplicate random numbers in our range. Then, delegate iteration to the iterator of your index hashset. Logic of "hasNext()" becomes trivial through delegate.

```
public class RandomIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private Iterator<Integer> indicies;

    List<T> delegate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();

        List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.generate(r::nextInt).limit(10).boxed().collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for(RandomIterator<Integer> test = new RandomIterator<>(numbers); test.hasNext(); ) {
            results.add(test.next());
        }
        System.out.println("In list: " + numbers);
        System.out.println("random iteration " + results);
        if(results.containsAll(numbers) && results.size() == numbers.size())
            System.out.println("Everything accounted for");
        else
            System.out.println("Something broke!");

    }

    public RandomIterator(List<T> delegate) {
        Random r = new Random();
        this.delegate = delegate;
        Set<Integer> indexSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        while(indexSet.size() != delegate.size())
            indexSet.add(r.nextInt(delegate.size()));

        System.out.println(indexSet);
        indicies = indexSet.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return indicies.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return delegate.get(indicies.next());
    }
}
```

If you just want an print 100 random numbers:

```
     IntStream.generate(r::nextInt).limit(100).forEach(System.out::println);
```

if you want an iterator (for whatever reason:)

```
IntStream.generate(r::nextInt).limit(100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()).iterator();
```

Comment: This solution is not space efficient. You might as well put all the numbers in an array, and shuffle.

Comment: You're right. @aykutfirat but it's easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: I was thinking on your phrase "space efficient" -- that's academic speak for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shuffling iterator that is very space&time-efficient when requesting only a few elements. It's very reasonable in all other cases too; runtime and space are both O(n). The only dynamic structure is a HashMap with up to half the size of the input list (although it will be much smaller near the beginning and the end) and Integer keys.

```
static <A> Iterator<A> shuffledIterator(final List<A> l) {
  return new Iterator<A>() {
    Random randomizer = new Random();
    int i = 0, n = l.size();
    HashMap<Integer, A> shuffled = new HashMap();

    public boolean hasNext() { return i < n; }

    public A next() {
      int j = i+randomizer.nextInt(n-i);
      A a = get(i), b = get(j);
      shuffled.put(j, a);
      shuffled.remove(i);
      ++i;
      return b;
    }

    A get(int i) {
      return shuffled.containsKey(i) ? shuffled.get(i) : l.get(i);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RandomIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

  private static final SecureRandom RANDOM = new SecureRandom();

  private final int[] order;

  private final List<T> elements;

  public RandomIterator(List<T> elements) {
     this.elements = elements;
     this.order = generateRandomOrder(elements.size());
  }

  private int[] generateRandomOrder(int size) {
     int[] index = new int[size];
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        index[i] = i;
     }

     int swap;
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int randomIndex = getRandomInt(0, size);
        swap = index[i];
        index[i] = index[randomIndex];
        index[randomIndex] = swap;
     }

     return index;
  }

  private int currentIndex = 0;

  private int getRandomInt(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
     return RANDOM.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound) + lowerBound;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
     return currentIndex != elements.size();
  }

  @Override
  public T next() {
     return elements.get(order[currentIndex++]);
  }
}
```

This only works if you guarantee that the elements in the list are placed in positions exactly between indexes [0,size).

You can use the normal Random if you are concerned about the performance penalty of SecureRandom (I prefer secure, yeah 8 times slower than normal random but secure!).