# Getting objects randomly from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary

I have an array which has 50 `Object`s in it.

I want to randomly get 4 objects from that `List` every time app launches.

And than put them in a `Map`.

How can i take randomly 4 objects from array?

Here is my code sample:

```
ArrayList<Deal> dealsTodayArray = dealsToday.getDeals(); 
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("dealsTodayFirst", dealsTodayFirst);
map.put("dealsTodaySecond", dealsTodaySecond);
map.put("dealsTodayThird", dealsTodayThird);
map.put("dealsTodayForth", dealsTodayForth);
```

Comment: Collections.shuffle(dealsTodayArray); and get the first, second, third, fourth elements with get?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887262/randomly-iterate-over-arraylistinteger-in-java

Comment: you can generate 4 random numbers b/w 1 and 50 and then choose members at those indices.

Comment: Do you mean `0` and `49` @sleekFish ?

Comment: @GáborBakos Post that as an answer. I think that's a nice solution.

Comment: Yeah i'd say so, @christopher.

Comment: is it like that? ArrayList<Deal> dealsTodayArray = dealsToday.getDeals();
   
   Collections.shuffle(dealsTodayArray);
   
   Deal dealsTodayFirst = dealsTodayArray.get(0);
   Deal dealsTodaySecond = dealsTodayArray.get(1);
   Deal dealsTodayThird = dealsTodayArray.get(2);
   Deal dealsTodayForth = dealsTodayArray.get(3);

Comment: Does `Collections.shuffle()` have O(n) complexity?

Comment: @sleekFish for 50 elements that is probably not a problem. (O(nlogn) probably)

Comment: Yeah, that's right. But for the general user, the method using `Random` might be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a combination of `Collections.shuffle` and `Collections.subList`:

```
List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
myStrings.add("a");
myStrings.add("b");
myStrings.add("c");
myStrings.add("d");
myStrings.add("e");
myStrings.add("f");
Collections.shuffle(myStrings);
System.out.println(myStrings.subList(0, 4));
```

**Output** (likely but not guaranteed to change at every execution):

```
[c, b, f, d]
```

Comment: I think this kind of approach is kinda overkill. If the resources are limited (or if the OP does not want his array modified), one should avoid using this approach.

Comment: @Joffrey It's valid to raise those concerns, however I expect it in 99% to be no issue and you would find out with profiling anyway. So no premature optimizations please.

Comment: @skiwi You're right about not wanting to optimize something that is not a problem. However, the very way of thinking it is more complicated than the naive approach, that's why it's bugging me. If you were asked to pull 4 cards out of a deck, you wouldn't go "let's shuffle the whole deck and then pick the 4 first cards" but rather pick cards at 4 random positions, wouldn't you?

Comment: That being said, we don't know if this `ArrayList` is used later in the code, but the collection will have to be copied if the original order matters.

Comment: @Joffrey you might if that was a 1-time operation :) But I do agree that my "solution" is not performance-aware, nor exceedingly elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Random` class to generate random indices within the bounds of your `ArrayList`.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int size = dealsTodayArray.size();
map.put("dealsTodayFirst", dealsTodayArray.get(rand.nextInt(size)));
// repeat with the 3 others...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `get` method, with the `Random` class. Use the `Random` class to generate the index of the element, and use the `get` method to retrieve it.

**Example**

```
Random random = new Random();

Deal deal = dealsTodayArray.get(random.nextInt(50));
// And repeat a few more times.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Random and in a loop generate an index to select and retrieve from list.

Answer (score 0):

If security is a concern here, try one of these approaches:

#### Approach 1

```
Random sr = new SecureRandom();
Collections.shuffle(dealsTodayArray, sr);

final int N = 4;
for( int i=0; i<N; i++ ) {
    map.put("dealsTodayFirst", dealsTodayArray.get(i));
}
```

#### Approach 2

```
Random sr = new SecureRandom();
final int N = 4;
final int len = dealsTodayArray.size();
for( int i=0; i<N; i++ ) {
    map.put("dealsTodayFirst", dealsTodayArray.get(sr.nextInt(len)));
}
```

Comment: I think this kind of approach is kinda overkill. If the resources are limited (or if the OP does not want his array modified), one should avoid using this approach.